# How to make **** in the vertical center of Textview

Tags: android

I have a Textview which content is **** , I want make **** in the vertical center of this Textview.
Any ideas for this problem?

Ps:The code as follow does not work.

```
   <TextView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:text="****"
              android:textColor="@color/bhTextColorPrimary"
              android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: what is the result?, the only I can see is that you are using android:layout_width="wrap_content" and android:layout_height="wrap_content" so I cannot see anything to center

Comment: use android:gravity center which make the data inside view to the gravity assigned.

Comment: @Azhagthott Sorry, I don't post full code, There is another TextView besides this Textview, Both of them in a center of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Asterisk Operator** [∗] ( U+2217) instead **Asterisk** [*] ( U+002A )

> **Asterisk Operator** is by default *vertically centered* on other hand **Asterisk** by
> default *align at top but cover full height of line*

**So even if you use `gravity` or `vertical-align` Asterisk never go in center of line**

```
<TextView  android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="\u2217"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/bhTextColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
```